# Include user named variables in existing python script

Tags: python, variables

Imagine you have program X that needs the following input by the user:

```
fy = 355.   #Yield stress (MPa)
fu = 552.   #Tensile stress resistance (MPa), 460 MPa in engineering stress
E = 210.E3   #Young modulus (MPa)
F = -100.E3   #vertical force (N)
k2_2=70.82e6   #stiffness 2nd segment 2L, strong axis (N.mm/rad)
loos=0.0055   #looseness 2L (rad), strong axis
bmax=3.5e6   #maximum moment 2L, strong axis (N.mm)
```

Then the user also wants to add an initially undetermined number of variables, a group started by `imp_local+str()` and another group by `imp_global+str()`.

The number of variables to generate depends on the result of reading a txt file.

The user is aware that the program cannot handle this generated variables, but looking at a macro created by the program there is maybe a chance of introducing them.

The macro generated by the program looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import modules
from math import *
from openturns import *
from phiboot import *


# define the physical model
class TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class( OpenTURNSPythonFunction ):

    def __init__( self ):
        OpenTURNSPythonFunction.__init__( self, 9, 1)
        self.logUser = LogUser()
        self.callsNumber = 0
        self.pad = 21

    def padVar(self, var):
        if type(var) == str:
            return var.ljust(self.pad)
        else:
            return str('%+.11e' % var).ljust(self.pad)

    def setLogFile(self, filename):
        self.callsNumber = 0
        self.logUser.setFile(filename)

    def closeLogFile(self):
        self.logUser.closeFile()

    # define OpenTURNS function
    def TP1_Simply_supported_beam( self, fy, fu, E, F, k2_2, loos, bmax ):
        # log header
        if self.callsNumber == 0:
            self.logUser.level1( ''.join(map(self.padVar, ['N', 'fy', 'fu', 'E', 'F', 'k2_2', 'loos', 'bmax', 'g'])) + '\n' )

        # log input vars
        self.logUser.level1( str(self.callsNumber).ljust(self.pad) + ''.join(map(self.padVar, [fy, fu, E, F, k2_2, loos, bmax]))
```

And the code to generate the groups of variables is:

```
fileData = [] #array with the input file

inputFile = open("C:/Abaqus_JOBS/Job-M1-3_4.inp", "r") #CAE INPUT FILE
#fileData = variable with all the lines of the inp file
for line in inputFile:
    fileData.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')])

fgenerate1=0
nTop=[]
for row,data in enumerate(fileData):
    if data[0]=="*Nset" and data[1]=="nset=TOP":
        row_Top = row
    if len(data)==3 and data[0]=="*Nset" and data[1]=="nset=TOP" and data[2]=="generate":
        fgenerate1=1
if row_Top!=0:
    for data in fileData[row_Top+1:]: # skip first row elements
        try:
            int(data[0])
        except ValueError:
            break # found bottom_row, stop iterating
        if  fgenerate1==0:   
            nTop.append(data)
        else:
            iniN=data[0]
            finN=int(data[1])+1
            inc=data[2]
            for n in range(int(iniN), int(finN), int(inc)):
                data=n
                nTop.append([str(data)])        
loc=locals()
for k,val in enumerate(nTop) : loc["imp_local"+str(k)]
for k,val in enumerate(nTop) : loc["imp_global"+str(k)]
```

Now that the user has generated the `imp_local` and `imp_global` variables he wants to add them to the corresponding lines in the program macro. How can he do it?

Comment: What does "add them to the corresponding lines in the program macro" mean?

Comment: @unutbu: add them to `def TP1_Simply_supported_beam( self, fy, fu, E, F, k2_2, loos, bmax ):`, `self.logUser.level1( ''.join(map(self.padVar, ['N', 'fy', 'fu', 'E', 'F', 'k2_2', 'loos', 'bmax', 'g'])) + '\n' )` and `self.logUser.level1( str(self.callsNumber).ljust(self.pad) + ''.join(map(self.padVar, [fy, fu, E, F, k2_2, loos, bmax]))`

Comment: Are we allowed to modify `TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class`?

Comment: Yes, but in the end `TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class` must have the same structure and must have the added variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you should avoid defining the variables in the global namespace. "Polluting" the global namespace with dynamically named variables is never useful, because it is hard to program with variables whose names you do not know until run time.

Instead, load the names and values into a new dict, `newvars`.
In other words, the "code that generates the group of variables" should end up defining

```
newvars = dict(
    fy = 355.,
    fu = 552.,
    E = 210.E3,
    F = -100.E3,
    k2_2=70.82e6,
    loos=0.0055,
    bmax=3.5e6,
    )
```

Then, you could define

```
def TP1_Simply_supported_beam(self, **kwargs):
    # log header
    if self.callsNumber == 0:
        self.logUser.level1(
            ''.join(map(self.padVar, ['N'] + kwargs.keys())) + '\n')

    # log input vars
    self.logUser.level1(
        str(self.callsNumber).ljust(self.pad) + ''.join(map(self.padVar, kwargs.values())
```

and use it like this:

```
obj = TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class()
obj.TP1_Simply_supported_beam(**newvars)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I just have a question: what's `kwargs`? Also, the last two lines are needed to recreate `class TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class( OpenTURNSPythonFunction ):`?

Comment: `kwargs` is what I chose to call the keyword argument variable name. When you put two asterisks, `**`, before a parameter name in a function definition, you are using a special syntax which tells Python to make a dict of all the keyword arguments and set it equal to `kwargs`. When you use `**newvars` when calling a function, the `**` tells Python to unpack the `dict` into keyword arguments. For full details, see [the saltycrane blog](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Comment: To summarize: `**` is the key ingredient in this suggested solution. It allows you to pass an *arbitrary number* of arguments to a function which do not have to be known until runtime.

Comment: just another clarification. shouldn't it be `obj = TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class( OpenTURNSPythonFunction )` instead of `obj = TP1_Simply_supported_beam_class()`? Thanks